What is the halacha on using netilat yadayim cups for non-hand washing purposes?
I know it is just a cup with two handles, but we have an extra netilat yadayim cup that is very decorative. I am okay with it being used for its intended purpose, but what is the law on using the cup for, say, a toothbrush holder, a vase, a soup bowl, etc.
TIA.

It doesn't say anywhere in the laws of Netilas Yadayim that you can't.

The cup used for Netilat Yadayim, even if it is designated - or even created - for the purpose of washing one’s hands, isn't a holy item. As such, one can use it for any purpose.
Source here:
https://www.yeshiva.co/ask/58242
"The cup does not have to be set aside for only this use – and one may take a cup that was used for drinking etc, and use it to wash with. One may also use a cup that was used for hand washing for other uses (such as drinking from, or watering the plants)."

It may seem self evident... but citation needed.

This isn't self evident to me. A hat is surely not even a mitzva at all, but we yet we find https://www.torahmusings.com/2011/01/taking-a-hat-into-a-bathroom/
